# java code showing Runtime error in online compiler

Tags: java

why this is showing runtime error in online compiler?
can someone explain me...
this code is running well in my netbeans but giving "RUNTIME ERROR" on virtual judge

problem statement:

//**

Even if the world is full of counterfeits, I still regard it as wonderful.

Pile up herbs and incense, and arise again from the flames and ashes of its predecessor — as is known to many, the phoenix does it like this.

The phoenix has a rather long lifespan, and reincarnates itself once every a! years. Here a! denotes the factorial of integer a, that is, a! = 1 × 2 × ... × a. Specifically, 0! = 1.

Koyomi doesn't care much about this, but before he gets into another mess with oddities, he is interested in the number of times the phoenix will reincarnate in a timespan of b! years, that is, . Note that when b ≥ a this value is always integer.

As the answer can be quite large, it would be enough for Koyomi just to know the last digit of the answer in decimal representation. And you're here to provide Koyomi with this knowledge.

Input
The first and only line of input contains two space-separated integers a and b (0 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ 1018).

Output
Output one line containing a single decimal digit — the last digit of the value that interests Koyomi.

Examples
Input
2 4
Output
2
Input
0 10
Output
0
Input
107 109
Output
2
Note
In the first example, the last digit of  is 2;

In the second example, the last digit of  is 0;

In the third example, the last digit of  is 2.

**//

thanks in advance....
i cannot find any fault in my code... what is the problem....
USER INPUTS:

Input

2 4

Output

2

Input

0 10

Output

0

Input

107 109

Output

2

GETTING "RUNTIME ERROR ON TEST 1"

```
package theeternalimortality;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static BigInteger fact(BigInteger x) {
        BigInteger a = new BigInteger("1");
        if (x.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
            return BigInteger.ONE;
        else
            return x.multiply(fact(x.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
        BigInteger a = (BigInteger.ONE);
        BigInteger b = (BigInteger.ONE);
        BigInteger ans = (BigInteger.ONE);
        BigInteger ans2 = (BigInteger.ONE);
        BigInteger ans3 = (BigInteger.ONE);
        a = ob.nextBigInteger();
        b = ob.nextBigInteger();

        ans = fact(a);
        ans2 = fact(b);

        ans3 = ans2.divide(ans);
        ans3 = ans3.mod(BigInteger.TEN);
        System.out.println(ans3);

    }

}
```

Comment: the user inputs are 2 4 output 2. giving runtime error in this test case but running smoothly in my java IDE

Comment: What's the problem? What runtime exception is it raising?

Comment: please explain more. Send the test and its result error.

Comment: Input
2 4
Output
2
Input
0 10
Output
0
Input
107 109
Output
2

Comment: IT IS GIVING "RUNTIME ERROR ON TEST 1" - TEST CASE 2 4 OUTPUT 2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it fails because of StackOverflow error. To escape this, use tail recursive algorithm

```
public static BigInteger fact(BigInteger x) {
    return factHelper(x, BigInteger.ONE);
}

pivate static BigInteger factHelper(BigInteger x, BigInteger acc) {
    if (x.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        return acc;
    else
        return factHelper(x.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), acc.multiply(x));
}
```

Comment: To get the last number of `a!/b!` you need just `a.mod(b)`, without any division

Comment: Try something like `if (a! > b!) answer = a.mod(b) else answer = b.mod(a)`

Comment: no its again wrong answer r you sure about it?  ans=fact(a);
        ans2=fact(b);
        
        if(ans.compareTo(ans2)==1){
        System.out.println(ans.mod(ans2));
        }
        else{
        System.out.println(ans2.mod(ans));        
        }

Comment: i am not getting why its showing runtime error.... because there is no fault in my code....

Comment: ohh I got it ... its because of the "package theeternalimortality;" header... though I got time limit exceed on text case 5 :D